# Rename returned ID's from the database PHP

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there's a way to define ID's returned from the database.I have a table called `vehicles` where it stores vehicle model ID.I return that id thgrough a loop because that table is connected to a user.The user car have more than one vehicle to his name.So I show that user his car's in the UCP.But what it show's me is the `vModel` ID.Is there any possible way of changing those ID's that come from the database to, let's say `vModel ID=100` and in the UCP the script show's to that user not the ID, but a defined value...let's say Lorem Ipsum...

Now it's like this:

> `Your vehicles - 142 , 162 , 155 etc.`

And what I need without changing the database structure:

> `Your vehicles - Ford , Bmw etc.`

UPDATE

These commands may be old and outdated but I'm just learning and doing this for my own usage.
My query:

```
$autoget = mysql_query("SELECT vModel FROM vehicles WHERE vOwner='$usernameshow' ");
echo'<li>Your vehicles:&nbsp';
while($autoshow = mysql_fetch_assoc($autoget))
{
echo'<div class="raudona-box">'.$autoshow['vModel'].'</div>&nbsp ';
}
```

My database structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEH6d.png -- cant post images :(

Comment: What are your database structures, and what is your current query?

Comment: How do you show it right now (PHP Code)?

Comment: Your db structure? anything u want to share?

Comment: you must have another table with model id's and names, right?

Comment: Umm...nope. Just this.Should I?

Comment: Well how do you know that 142 is Ford? you should have that info somewhere

Comment: That's why I'm here.What should I do, what should I specify and where to store that information.The UCP is connected to a game server, and that server know's inside it's own script what ID is what Model.And only inserts ID's to Mysql.

Comment: Okay I created a new table `vmodel` containing ID's and Model names.And how do I associate those with the table `vehicles`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have a table with the models:

```
SELECT m.model FROM vehicles v LEFT JOIN vmodel m ON v.vModel = m.ID WHERE vOwner='$usernameshow'
```

The column names would change based on your own database structure

Comment: Another question, maybe you would know why this code wont work on a webserver, but it works perfectly fine in localhost.Might it be because of not using mysqli or something like that? :(

Comment: Make sure your tables are the same in both places. Other than that, it would depend on the error message.

Comment: I checked the tables and everything seems fine, and I get no error message with `echo mysql_error();`

Comment: Is the data exactly the same in both databases?